# GWT:place the items in verticalpanel in descending order

Tags: gwt

I have a verticalpanel and a button 
whenever i click on button a new label added to my verticalpanel in ascending order

```
       like this (Inside my verticalPanel)

        1stlabel
        2ndlabel
        3rdlabel
```

Whereas i want it to be in descinding order , the latest should be at the top

```
     like this (Inside my verticalPanel)

        3rdlabel
        2ndlabel
        1stlabel
```

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I recall you can achieve this with

```
yourVerticalPanel.insert( yourWidget , beforeIndex )
```

Just use `beforeIndex == 0` and you should be fine.